# Apache Openssl : error in SSLv2/v3 read client hello A

Tags: apache-2.2, openssl

### Some Background:

I am trying to setup reverse proxy for my internal business users for site validation when the external route is down. I am able to setup multiple routes with corresponding virtualhosts entries in httpd.conf for port 80 : anonymous user. Am afraid am stuck at SSL route and unable to make progress. I have been to multiple forums but unable to find a response which assists me in moving further.

### Server Details:

Apache version: Apache/2.2.29 (Unix)
Linux Version: 
$ cat /etc/*-release
Enterprise Linux Enterprise Linux Server release 5.8 (Carthage)
Oracle Linux Server release 5.8
Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server release 5.8 (Tikanga)

### Problem:

**> When I try to access over SSL (*:443) I get empty response on all 3 browsers (IE/Chrome/Firefox)**

Note: I generated self signed certificate following instructions at :

www.sslshopper.com/article-how-to-create-and-install-an-apache-self-signed-certificate.html

### ***Troubleshooting So far:***

===========
**Error Log**

```
[Wed Jul 08 23:16:06 2015] [notice] Digest: generating secret for digest authentication ...
[Wed Jul 08 23:16:06 2015] [notice] Digest: done
[Wed Jul 08 23:16:06 2015] [debug] util_ldap.c(1990): LDAP merging Shared Cache conf: shm=0x21b6ff0 rmm=0x21b7048 for VHOST: stgwww.cos.agilent.com
[Wed Jul 08 23:16:06 2015] [debug] util_ldap.c(1990): LDAP merging Shared Cache conf: shm=0x21b6ff0 rmm=0x21b7048 for VHOST: stgwww.cos.agilent.com
[Wed Jul 08 23:16:06 2015] [info] APR LDAP: Built with OpenLDAP LDAP SDK
[Wed Jul 08 23:16:06 2015] [info] LDAP: SSL support available
[Wed Jul 08 23:16:06 2015] [info] mod_unique_id: using ip addr 127.0.0.1
[Wed Jul 08 23:16:07 2015] [info] Init: Seeding PRNG with 144 bytes of entropy
[Wed Jul 08 23:16:07 2015] [info] Loading certificate & private key of SSL-aware server
[Wed Jul 08 23:16:07 2015] [debug] ssl_engine_pphrase.c(470): unencrypted RSA private key - pass phrase not required
[Wed Jul 08 23:16:07 2015] [info] Init: Generating temporary RSA private keys (512/1024 bits)
[Wed Jul 08 23:16:07 2015] [info] Init: Generating temporary DH parameters (512/1024 bits)
[Wed Jul 08 23:16:07 2015] [debug] ssl_scache_shmcb.c(253): shmcb_init allocated 512000 bytes of shared memory
[Wed Jul 08 23:16:07 2015] [debug] ssl_scache_shmcb.c(272): for 511920 bytes (512000 including header), recommending 32 subcaches, 133 indexes each
[Wed Jul 08 23:16:07 2015] [debug] ssl_scache_shmcb.c(306): shmcb_init_memory choices follow
[Wed Jul 08 23:16:07 2015] [debug] ssl_scache_shmcb.c(308): subcache_num = 32
[Wed Jul 08 23:16:07 2015] [debug] ssl_scache_shmcb.c(310): subcache_size = 15992
[Wed Jul 08 23:16:07 2015] [debug] ssl_scache_shmcb.c(312): subcache_data_offset = 3208
[Wed Jul 08 23:16:07 2015] [debug] ssl_scache_shmcb.c(314): subcache_data_size = 12784
[Wed Jul 08 23:16:07 2015] [debug] ssl_scache_shmcb.c(316): index_num = 133
[Wed Jul 08 23:16:07 2015] [info] Shared memory session cache initialised
[Wed Jul 08 23:16:07 2015] [info] Init: Initializing (virtual) servers for SSL
[Wed Jul 08 23:16:07 2015] [info] Configuring server for SSL protocol
[Wed Jul 08 23:16:07 2015] [debug] ssl_engine_init.c(521): Creating new SSL context (protocols: SSLv3, TLSv1)
[Wed Jul 08 23:16:07 2015] [debug] ssl_engine_init.c(759): Configuring permitted SSL ciphers [HIGH:MEDIUM:!aNULL:!MD5]
[Wed Jul 08 23:16:07 2015] [debug] ssl_engine_init.c(843): Configuring server certificate chain (1 CA certificate)
[Wed Jul 08 23:16:07 2015] [debug] ssl_engine_init.c(890): Configuring RSA server certificate
[Wed Jul 08 23:16:07 2015] [debug] ssl_engine_init.c(936): Configuring RSA server private key
[Wed Jul 08 23:16:07 2015] [debug] ssl_engine_init.c(521): Creating new SSL context (protocols: SSLv2, SSLv3, TLSv1)
[Wed Jul 08 23:16:07 2015] [info] mod_ssl/2.2.29 compiled against Server: Apache/2.2.29, Library: OpenSSL/0.9.8e-fips-rhel5
[Wed Jul 08 23:16:07 2015] [debug] proxy_util.c(1829): proxy: grabbed scoreboard slot 11 in child 6098 for worker proxy:reverse
[Wed Jul 08 23:16:07 2015] [debug] proxy_util.c(1945): proxy: initialized single connection worker 11 in child 6098 for (*)
---------
truncated for ease of reading
---------
[Wed Jul 08 23:19:02 2015] [info] [client 192.168.244.1] Connection to child 0 established (server stgwww.cos.agilent.com:443)
[Wed Jul 08 23:19:02 2015] [info] Seeding PRNG with 144 bytes of entropy
[Wed Jul 08 23:19:02 2015] [debug] ssl_engine_kernel.c(1903): OpenSSL: Handshake: start
[Wed Jul 08 23:19:02 2015] [debug] ssl_engine_kernel.c(1911): OpenSSL: Loop: before/accept initialization
[Wed Jul 08 23:19:02 2015] [debug] ssl_engine_io.c(1939): OpenSSL: read 11/11 bytes from BIO#22341b0 [mem: 223b880] (BIO dump follows)
[Wed Jul 08 23:19:02 2015] [debug] ssl_engine_io.c(1872): +-------------------------------------------------------------------------+
[Wed Jul 08 23:19:02 2015] [debug] ssl_engine_io.c(1911): | 0000: 43 4f 4e 4e 45 43 54 20-73 74 67                 CONNECT stg      |
[Wed Jul 08 23:19:02 2015] [debug] ssl_engine_io.c(1917): +-------------------------------------------------------------------------+
**[Wed Jul 08 23:19:02 2015] [debug] ssl_engine_kernel.c(1940): OpenSSL: Exit: error in SSLv2/v3 read client hello A
[Wed Jul 08 23:19:02 2015] [info] [client 192.168.244.1] SSL library error 1 in handshake (server stgwww.cos.agilent.com:443)
[Wed Jul 08 23:19:02 2015] [info] SSL Library Error: 336027803 error:1407609B:SSL routines:SSL23_GET_CLIENT_HELLO:https proxy request speaking HTTP to HTTPS port!?
[Wed Jul 08 23:19:02 2015] [info] [client 192.168.244.1] Connection closed to child 0 with abortive shutdown (server stgwww.cos.agilent.com:443)**
[Wed Jul 08 23:19:02 2015] [info] [client 192.168.244.1] Connection to child 1 established (server stgwww.cos.agilent.com:443)
[Wed Jul 08 23:19:02 2015] [info] Seeding PRNG with 144 bytes of entropy
[Wed Jul 08 23:19:02 2015] [debug] ssl_engine_kernel.c(1903): OpenSSL: Handshake: start
[Wed Jul 08 23:19:02 2015] [debug] ssl_engine_kernel.c(1911): OpenSSL: Loop: before/accept initialization
[Wed Jul 08 23:19:02 2015] [debug] ssl_engine_io.c(1939): OpenSSL: read 11/11 bytes from BIO#22341b0 [mem: 223b880] (BIO dump follows)
[Wed Jul 08 23:19:02 2015] [debug] ssl_engine_io.c(1872): +-------------------------------------------------------------------------+
[Wed Jul 08 23:19:02 2015] [debug] ssl_engine_io.c(1911): | 0000: 43 4f 4e 4e 45 43 54 20-73 74 67                 CONNECT stg      |
[Wed Jul 08 23:19:02 2015] [debug] ssl_engine_io.c(1917): +-------------------------------------------------------------------------+
[Wed Jul 08 23:19:02 2015] [debug] ssl_engine_kernel.c(1940): OpenSSL: Exit: error in SSLv2/v3 read client hello A
[Wed Jul 08 23:19:02 2015] [info] [client 192.168.244.1] SSL library error 1 in handshake (server stgwww.cos.agilent.com:443)
[Wed Jul 08 23:19:02 2015] [info] SSL Library Error: 336027803 error:1407609B:SSL routines:SSL23_GET_CLIENT_HELLO:https proxy request speaking HTTP to HTTPS port!?
[Wed Jul 08 23:19:02 2015] [info] [client 192.168.244.1] Connection closed to child 1 with abortive shutdown (server stgwww.cos.agilent.com:443)
[Wed Jul 08 23:19:02 2015] [info] [client 192.168.244.1] Connection to child 4 established (server stgwww.cos.agilent.com:443)
[Wed Jul 08 23:19:02 2015] [info] Seeding PRNG with 144 bytes of entropy
[Wed Jul 08 23:19:02 2015] [debug] ssl_engine_kernel.c(1903): OpenSSL: Handshake: start
[Wed Jul 08 23:19:02 2015] [debug] ssl_engine_kernel.c(1911): OpenSSL: Loop: before/accept initialization
[Wed Jul 08 23:19:02 2015] [debug] ssl_engine_io.c(1939): OpenSSL: read 11/11 bytes from BIO#22341b0 [mem: 223b880] (BIO dump follows)
```

===========
**Open SSL Check**

```
[sandeep@atgweb logs]$ openssl s_client -connect  192.168.244.129:443 -state -nbio
CONNECTED(00000003)
turning on non blocking io
SSL_connect:before/connect initialization
SSL_connect:SSLv2/v3 write client hello A
**SSL_connect:error in SSLv2/v3 read server hello A
write R BLOCK**
SSL_connect:SSLv3 read server hello A
depth=0 /C=US/ST=California/L=Cupertino/O=Agilent/OU=IT/CN=stgwww.cos.agilent.com/emailAddress=sandeep_rohilla@agilent.com
**verify error:num=18:self signed certificate**
verify return:1
depth=0 /C=US/ST=California/L=Cupertino/O=Agilent/OU=IT/CN=stgwww.cos.agilent.com/emailAddress=sandeep_rohilla@agilent.com
verify return:1
SSL_connect:SSLv3 read server certificate A
SSL_connect:SSLv3 read server key exchange A
SSL_connect:SSLv3 read server done A
SSL_connect:SSLv3 write client key exchange A
SSL_connect:SSLv3 write change cipher spec A
SSL_connect:SSLv3 write finished A
SSL_connect:SSLv3 flush data
SSL_connect:error in SSLv3 read finished A
SSL_connect:error in SSLv3 read finished A
read R BLOCK
SSL_connect:SSLv3 read finished A
read R BLOCK
---
Certificate chain
 0 s:/C=US/ST=California/L=Cupertino/O=Agilent/OU=IT/CN=stgwww.cos.agilent.com/emailAddress=sandeep_rohilla@agilent.com
   i:/C=US/ST=California/L=Cupertino/O=Agilent/OU=IT/CN=stgwww.cos.agilent.com/emailAddress=sandeep_rohilla@agilent.com
 1 s:/C=US/ST=California/L=Cupertino/O=Agilent/OU=IT/CN=atgweb.localvm.com/emailAddress=sandeep_rohilla@agilent.com
   i:/C=US/ST=California/L=Cupertino/O=Agilent/OU=IT/CN=atgweb.localvm.com/emailAddress=sandeep_rohilla@agilent.com
---
Server certificate
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----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-----END CERTIFICATE-----
subject=/C=US/ST=California/L=Cupertino/O=Agilent/OU=IT/CN=stgwww.cos.agilent.com/emailAddress=sandeep_rohilla@agilent.com
issuer=/C=US/ST=California/L=Cupertino/O=Agilent/OU=IT/CN=stgwww.cos.agilent.com/emailAddress=sandeep_rohilla@agilent.com
---
No client certificate CA names sent
---
SSL handshake has read 2509 bytes and written 319 bytes
---
New, TLSv1/SSLv3, Cipher is DHE-RSA-AES256-SHA
Server public key is 1024 bit
Secure Renegotiation IS supported
Compression: NONE
Expansion: NONE
SSL-Session:
    Protocol  : TLSv1
    Cipher    : DHE-RSA-AES256-SHA
    Session-ID: EE96B79CC47110B9A7B242691F1721DE77A3119F001CC88CE3B9BEFB4433D8D1
    Session-ID-ctx: 
    Master-Key: 30CB866077089FD7198DBD08EEAD9A98C58E43563A191FA2FA8E7A967963E4A614F53045C8528B0978ABD0285ACC41FE
    Key-Arg   : None
    Krb5 Principal: None
    Start Time: 1436378586
    Timeout   : 300 (sec)
    Verify return code: 18 (self signed certificate)
---
SSL3 alert read:warning:close notify
closed
SSL3 alert write:warning:close notify
[sandeep@atgweb logs]$ cd ..
[sandeep@atgweb apache2]$ cd bin
[sandeep@atgweb bin]$ sudo ./apachectl -version
Server version: Apache/2.2.29 (Unix)
Server built:   May 21 2015 21:05:01
```

===============
**HTTPD-SSL.CONF File**

```
#
#SSLRandomSeed startup file:/dev/random  512
#SSLRandomSeed startup file:/dev/urandom 512
#SSLRandomSeed connect file:/dev/random  512
#SSLRandomSeed connect file:/dev/urandom 512


Listen 443
NameVirtualHost *:443

#   Some MIME-types for downloading Certificates and CRLs
#
AddType application/x-x509-ca-cert .crt
AddType application/x-pkcs7-crl    .crl

SSLPassPhraseDialog  builtin

SSLSessionCache        "shmcb:/usr/local/apache2/logs/ssl_scache(512000)"
SSLSessionCacheTimeout  300
SSLMutex  "file:/usr/local/apache2/logs/ssl_mutex"

##
## SSL Virtual Host Context
##

<VirtualHost _default_:443>

#   General setup for the virtual host
DocumentRoot "/usr/local/apache2/htdocs"
ServerName xxxxx:443
ServerAdmin you@example.com
ErrorLog "/usr/local/apache2/logs/error_log"
TransferLog "/usr/local/apache2/logs/access_log"

#   Enable/Disable SSL for this virtual host.
SSLEngine on

#   SSL Protocol support:
SSLProtocol all -SSLv2

#   SSL Cipher Suite:
SSLCipherSuite HIGH:MEDIUM:!aNULL:!MD5


#   Server Certificate:
SSLCertificateFile "/usr/local/apache2/conf/ssl.crt"

#   Server Private Key:
SSLCertificateKeyFile "/usr/local/apache2/conf/ssl.key"

#   Server Certificate Chain:
SSLCertificateChainFile "/home/sandeep/sandeep.crt"

<FilesMatch "\.(cgi|shtml|phtml|php)$">
    SSLOptions +StdEnvVars
</FilesMatch>
<Directory "/usr/local/apache2/cgi-bin">
    SSLOptions +StdEnvVars
</Directory>


BrowserMatch "MSIE [2-5]" \
         nokeepalive ssl-unclean-shutdown \
         downgrade-1.0 force-response-1.0

#   Per-Server Logging:
CustomLog "/usr/local/apache2/logs/ssl_request_log" \
          "%t %h %{SSL_PROTOCOL}x %{SSL_CIPHER}x \"%r\" %b"

SSLProxyEngine on
SSLProxyVerify none

SetEnvIf User-Agent ".*MSIE.*" nokeepalive ssl-unclean-shutdown
CustomLog logs/ssl_request_log \
   "%t %h %{SSL_PROTOCOL}x %{SSL_CIPHER}x \"%r\" %b"

ProxyPass / http://www.google.com
ProxyPassReverse / http://www.google.com
</VirtualHost>
```

===============
**Modules Enabled**

```
LoadModule authn_file_module modules/mod_authn_file.so
LoadModule authn_dbm_module modules/mod_authn_dbm.so
LoadModule authn_anon_module modules/mod_authn_anon.so
LoadModule authn_dbd_module modules/mod_authn_dbd.so
LoadModule authn_default_module modules/mod_authn_default.so
LoadModule authn_alias_module modules/mod_authn_alias.so
LoadModule authz_host_module modules/mod_authz_host.so
LoadModule authz_groupfile_module modules/mod_authz_groupfile.so
LoadModule authz_user_module modules/mod_authz_user.so
LoadModule authz_dbm_module modules/mod_authz_dbm.so
LoadModule authz_owner_module modules/mod_authz_owner.so
LoadModule authnz_ldap_module modules/mod_authnz_ldap.so
LoadModule authz_default_module modules/mod_authz_default.so
LoadModule auth_basic_module modules/mod_auth_basic.so
LoadModule auth_digest_module modules/mod_auth_digest.so
LoadModule file_cache_module modules/mod_file_cache.so
LoadModule cache_module modules/mod_cache.so
LoadModule disk_cache_module modules/mod_disk_cache.so
LoadModule mem_cache_module modules/mod_mem_cache.so
LoadModule dbd_module modules/mod_dbd.so
LoadModule dumpio_module modules/mod_dumpio.so
LoadModule echo_module modules/mod_echo.so
LoadModule reqtimeout_module modules/mod_reqtimeout.so
LoadModule ext_filter_module modules/mod_ext_filter.so
LoadModule include_module modules/mod_include.so
LoadModule filter_module modules/mod_filter.so
LoadModule substitute_module modules/mod_substitute.so
LoadModule charset_lite_module modules/mod_charset_lite.so
LoadModule deflate_module modules/mod_deflate.so
LoadModule ldap_module modules/mod_ldap.so
LoadModule log_config_module modules/mod_log_config.so
LoadModule log_forensic_module modules/mod_log_forensic.so
LoadModule logio_module modules/mod_logio.so
LoadModule env_module modules/mod_env.so
LoadModule mime_magic_module modules/mod_mime_magic.so
LoadModule cern_meta_module modules/mod_cern_meta.so
LoadModule expires_module modules/mod_expires.so
LoadModule headers_module modules/mod_headers.so
LoadModule ident_module modules/mod_ident.so
LoadModule usertrack_module modules/mod_usertrack.so
LoadModule unique_id_module modules/mod_unique_id.so
LoadModule setenvif_module modules/mod_setenvif.so
LoadModule version_module modules/mod_version.so
LoadModule proxy_module modules/mod_proxy.so
LoadModule proxy_connect_module modules/mod_proxy_connect.so
LoadModule proxy_ftp_module modules/mod_proxy_ftp.so
LoadModule proxy_http_module modules/mod_proxy_http.so
LoadModule proxy_scgi_module modules/mod_proxy_scgi.so
LoadModule proxy_ajp_module modules/mod_proxy_ajp.so
LoadModule proxy_balancer_module modules/mod_proxy_balancer.so
LoadModule ssl_module modules/mod_ssl.so
LoadModule mime_module modules/mod_mime.so
LoadModule dav_module modules/mod_dav.so
LoadModule status_module modules/mod_status.so
LoadModule autoindex_module modules/mod_autoindex.so
LoadModule asis_module modules/mod_asis.so
LoadModule info_module modules/mod_info.so
LoadModule cgi_module modules/mod_cgi.so
LoadModule dav_fs_module modules/mod_dav_fs.so
LoadModule dav_lock_module modules/mod_dav_lock.so
LoadModule vhost_alias_module modules/mod_vhost_alias.so
LoadModule negotiation_module modules/mod_negotiation.so
LoadModule dir_module modules/mod_dir.so
LoadModule imagemap_module modules/mod_imagemap.so
LoadModule actions_module modules/mod_actions.so
LoadModule speling_module modules/mod_speling.so
LoadModule userdir_module modules/mod_userdir.so
LoadModule alias_module modules/mod_alias.so
LoadModule rewrite_module modules/mod_rewrite.so
```

#

I will really appreciate help on this. It has been days I have been hitting my head to the wall. Also I am new to this, if I have missed something basic my apologies.

Cheers,
Sandeep

Answer (score 0):

```
Your SSL Library Error: 336027803 error:1407609B:SSL routines:SSL23_GET_CLIENT_HELLO:https proxy request speaking HTTP to HTTPS port!?
```

due to

```
ProxyPass / http://www.google.com
ProxyPassReverse / http://www.google.com
```

You should try

```
ProxyPass / https://www.google.com
ProxyPassReverse / https://www.google.com
```